# How to get PayPal payout's transaction ID

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using paypal php SDK.

And after create a `\PayPal\Api\Payout`, there is a `payout_batch_id` in the `PayoutBatchHeader`, and these is also a `transaction_id` in the `PayoutItemDetails`. But they didn't match the Payment id, which I can search in my account's activity.

My question is how can I get the `payment_id`?